# selecting minimum from top of all stacks

Tags: c++, heap

I am trying to implement patience sorting .

Now i want to do the following but not able to to so :

1) select(pop) minimum element from top of given piles . If pile `a` and pile `b` , both contains the minimum value , pop from pile `a` , where `a < b` .
2) keep on doing so till all piles are empty .

How to do this using `heap` ?

I am making vector of stacks (piles) in this way :

```
void patience_sort()
{
    typedef std::stack<int> PileType;
    std::vector<PileType>::iterator insert_it;
    std::vector<PileType> piles;

    for ( it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++)
    {
        PileType new_pile;
        new_pile.push(*it);
        insert_it =std::lower_bound(piles.begin(), piles.end(), new_pile, pile_less<PileType>);

        if (insert_it == piles.end())
            piles.push_back(new_pile);
        else
            insert_it->push(*it);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, does your question boil down to implementing stack using heap?

Comment: It is hard to grasp what your stack population code exactly does. Every next stack element in `piles` contains elements greater than previous stack - is that what you try to accomplish ? What is your `pile_less` ?

Comment: @mangusta: yes this is just the way to make the piles , the main thing to do is how to find minimum element from all the stacks one by one .

Comment: @aseem why do you need stacks then? you could use lists. stack is used when you're interested in ORDER of insertion, rather than VALUE of inserted elements